# JSONArray cannot add on Response method

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Cannot work for `public void onResponse(JSONArray response)`

```
public void sendRequest(){

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, request_url, null, new Response.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {




            for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){

                SliderUtils sliderUtils = new SliderUtils();

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    sliderUtils.setSliderImageUrl(jsonObject.getString("image_url"));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sliderImg.add(sliderUtils);
        }
```

Comment: There are many possible apps that could respond to an `ACTION_PICK` `Intent`. Your one test device happens to have these two. The other ~2 billion Android devices will have others. There is no single "Gallery" app pre-installed across the ~10,000 Android device models, plus others that the user can install themselves. Please just allow the user to use what they want.

Comment: I think this question should be closed as "Unclear what you are asking". If you can improve it by editing it, please do.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

Try Above code

Comment: `ACTION_PICK` [does not use a MIME type](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK). It does use a `Uri`, which your code lacks. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` uses a MIME type (instead of a `Uri`).

Comment: Thanks bro...i have tried but some mobile (particularly nokia 6) can not remove photos option could you help me?

Comment: i have tried all above type but still show like that image...could you help me? any another method

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
getIntent.setType("image/*");

Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        pickIntent.setType("image/*");

/*Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Select Image");
       chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{pickIntent});*/

startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, "Select Image"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

Try this code snippet, also try commented code once.

Comment: i have tried all above type but still show like that image...could you help me? any another method